# Is convergence in law compatible with arithmetic?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge in law to $X$ and $y$ respectively, **where $y$ is a constant**. Then are the following true?

1. $X_nY_n \to yX$
2. $X_n + Y_n \to X + y$
3. $X_n/Y_n \to X/y$ (if $y\neq 0$)

These statements are obviously true for almost sure convergence, but what about convergence in probability? For convergence in distribution? In the convergence in distribution case I think we may have to suppose $Y_n$ converges to a constant.

I'd also be interested in references for these statements, because I can't find anything online.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly $Y_n \overset{d}\to y \implies Y_n \overset{P}\to y$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propB1). So, you may directly apply [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky's_theorem) to obtain that all statements 1.-3. are indeed true under your assumptions. So, Slutsky's theorem and the properties listed in the link, answer indeed your questions:

1. *These statements are obviously true for almost sure convergence, but what about convergence in probability?*: Yes, they are true (Note 3. in the link).
2. *For convergence in distribution?* Yes, they are true (Note 1. in the link).
3. *In the convergence in distribution case I think we may have to suppose $Y_n$ converges to a constant*. I do not directly understand this question, because you have already assumed that. But, yes, this assumption is necessary (Note 2. in the link).